# Facebook Fql Query to status table -- not working php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I have this pretty stock generic code. If i'm logged in (app admin) it shows all my status. If I log in with any other user, it shows nothing. Why?

```
  <?php 
 header('p3p: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"');

include_once('facebook.php');


     $app_id = '289544004746';


// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => '289544004746',
  'secret' => '5772f9f5abbcc84e794c28169a399d4e',
  'cookie' => true,
));


$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'http://autobotcentral.info/logout.php'));
echo "<a href='$logoutUrl'>Log out </a>";
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_activities,user_status,read_status'));
echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>";
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
</html> 
<?php
}


$result = $facebook->api(array(
    'query' => 'SELECT uid,status_id,message FROM status WHERE uid = me()', 
    'method' => 'fql.query'));
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to receive `user_status` extended permision to retrieve user's status

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

You can do that using [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.login/)